# XML parsing - algorithm

Tags: c, xml

i have this following schema

```
<dataset>
   <record>
      <A> </A>
      <B> </B>
   </record>

   <record>
      <A> </A>
      <B> </B>
   </record>
</dataset>
```

Can you suggest an efficient algorithm to parse the 'record's and store them in a c structure?

Straightforward parsing is taking a long time as the number of records is around 1500. Any changes to be made in the schema are also welcome.

Comment: Use a library, there are a few to pick from. Parsing XML is *hard*.

Comment: Algorithm: 1. Download XML library
2. Use xml library with xpath to access elements

Comment: When you say "parsing is taking a long time", are you saying you have written your own parser, rather than using one off-the-shelf? In that case, it's not surprising that it takes a long time, and the answer is to use an off-the-shelf parser, which will be far more efficient than anything you are likely to write yourself.

Comment: I am using the libraries in Labwindows CVI.

Comment: Try to use the algorithm like evaluation of postfix expression using stacks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest not re-inventing an algorithm and using an XML-parser instead. For reasons check this masterly answer on why not to use RegEx on XHTML: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) (I admit parsing XHTML is even harder, but things like occasional occuring attributes are the same and the accepted answer is really worth reading)

Answer (score 0):

You are concerned about runtime - are you on an embedded device?
If so you could preprocess the xml into a format that is easy to parse on the microcontroller.